# AWS Glue spark optimize join

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I have an embarassingly parallel problem: Two tables which I JDBC query from Oracle using `key1` as a `hashfield` to Glue. The tables ought to be joined by this same key and written to s3. To my understanding the ideal spark job would be just one stage where a given worker queries a portion of both tables, joins them in memory (increasing the number of connections such that the joined table portions fit in memory of a single task) and writes to s3. no shuffle required.

This is my JDBC query context:

```
table_a = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="oracle",
    connection_options={
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable":"table_a"
        "hashfield":"key1"
    },
   ...
)
```

and similarly for `table_b`. I can confirm parallel queries in oracle logs

```sql
SELECT * FROM (select * from table_a WHERE MOD(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(STANDARD_HASH("key1"), -8, 8), 'xxxxxxxx'), 7) = 4) table_a
...
SELECT * FROM (select * from table_b WHERE MOD(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(STANDARD_HASH("key1"), -8, 8), 'xxxxxxxx'), 7) = 4) table_b
```

and also in spark UI 7 connections (7 si the dedault). so I would expect the individual workers to receive the "same batches".
However in the spark ui I can see the next operation being a union operation which results in a shuffle write of all my data slowing down my job considerably which must stem from this join:

```py
table_a.toDF()).createOrReplaceTempView("table_a")
table_b.toDF()).createOrReplaceTempView("table_b")
result = spark.sql("""SELECT table_a.VALUE, table_b.* 
                      FROM table_a
                      JOIN table_b on table_a.key1 = table_b.key1"""
)
merged = DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext)
```

Finally I prepare a sink:

```py
sink = glueContext.getSink(
    path = "s3://...",
    ...)
    
sink.setFormat("glueparquet").writeFramge(merged)
```

It *works*, but the shuffle write/read slows it down. There must be a way to explain to glue that this join can be done in parallel?

Comment: Before performing the join eliminate the records which has null value in join keys. Check if the join key values are evenly distributed or they are uneven. If there is an uneven distribution, then there is a high possibility of join taking more time.